# Does $\alpha$ and $p$ commute where $\alpha$ is a Dirac matrix and $p$ is a momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, commutator, dirac-matrices

Can I write $\langle\psi\vert\alpha.p\vert\psi\rangle$ as $\langle\psi\vert p.\alpha\vert\psi\rangle$ ?

Comment: Yes, α is a matrix of numbers.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Not all matrices commute though

Comment: @Wolfram johny  *p* is not a matrix,  but even if you represented it as one, it would act on a radically different space, the essence of Dirac's construction!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Exactly, that is why they commute, not because they are "numbers".

Comment: Never mind… you don’t speak our language. Numbers means inert to the action of the gradient, in our waters….

Answer (score 3):

Yes, these two quantities live/act in different spaces and thus they commute. Specifically, the dirac matrix $\alpha$ (whichever dirac matrix $\gamma^\mu$ you choose), is not an operator on the Hilbert space the same way that $p$ is. It doesn't act on state vectors in the hilbert space the same way $p$ does. The dirac matricies do not represent observables.

Answer (score 2):

The Dirac matrices $\alpha_n$ and the momentum operators
$p_n=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}$ commute for a very simple reason.

The Dirac matrices scramble the spinor components,
but do so independent of position $\mathbf{x}$.
And the momentum operators operate dependent on position $\mathbf{x}$,
but do so equally for all spinor components.

So when you for example calculate
$$\begin{align}
p_x \alpha_x |\psi\rangle
&=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
  \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}\psi_1\\\psi_2\\\psi_3\\\psi_4\end{pmatrix} \\
&=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
  \begin{pmatrix}\psi_4\\\psi_3\\\psi_2\\\psi_1\end{pmatrix} \\
&=-i\hbar
  \begin{pmatrix}\partial\psi_4/\partial x\\\partial\psi_3/\partial x\\
  \partial\psi_2/\partial x\\\partial\psi_1/\partial x\end{pmatrix}  
\end{align}$$

then you get the same as
$$\begin{align}
\alpha_xp_x |\psi\rangle
&=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
  (-i\hbar)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
  \begin{pmatrix}\psi_1\\\psi_2\\\psi_3\\\psi_4\end{pmatrix} \\
&=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
 (-i\hbar)
 \begin{pmatrix}\partial\psi_1/\partial x\\\partial\psi_2/\partial x\\
  \partial\psi_3/\partial x\\\partial\psi_4/\partial x\end{pmatrix} \\
&=-i\hbar
  \begin{pmatrix}\partial\psi_4/\partial x\\\partial\psi_3/\partial x\\
  \partial\psi_2/\partial x\\\partial\psi_1/\partial x\end{pmatrix}  
\end{align}$$